# Difference between apt-get compilation and manual compilation from source

Tags: apt, compiling, libraries

I am trying to replace manually a library for freeradius.
On a one hand I installed freeradius with an apt-get install. There was a library "libfoo-2.0.4.so" (let's call it the lib(apt)).
On the other hand I used the sources (from apt-get source) to modify the library "libfoo-2.0.4.so" (let's call it the lib(src)). The i compiled the sources (./configure, make) to retrieve this modified lib(src). (The lib works fine when i test it).

When I try to manually replace lib(apt) by lib(src) the freeradius segfaults during the call of that library.
So it seems that the libraries are not compatible.

Could it be because of **compilation** issues? (precompiled version versus local compilation)
Or **build option** issues?

Thanks!
ps: i am kind of new to these websites so i'm not sure i'm posting this in the right place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install library or any other package using apt-get, it is always stable so most recommended because they are tested and repositories are well maintained by developers. When you install library or any other packages by  compiling source code , chances are less to be stable. Sometimes it also causes problems.

Replacing src with apt versions of library will be not compatible and creates problems.

For more Information glance at [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Source_or_Binary.3F).

Comment: Hi @K.K Patel, Thanks for your answer. I figured out that it might be caused by different build options (like with ./configure). 
Are you saying that even with the same build options the lib files won't be compatible?